# What's the cleanest way to import a third party library with webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm trying to use [BeePlugin package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mailupinc/bee-plugin) in a Rails project and it raised the question of how to import properly a library using Webpacker?

I added jQuery but somehow I can't add bee-plugin.
I wanna be able to import **just what I need and only in the file I need it**

So far what I did was

1. Install the library with yarn `yarn add @mailupinc/bee-plugin`
2. Created a new file to add my code and import it in *application.js* `import ./bee`
3. In the new file import my library. I have tried

   - `import "@mailupinc/bee-plugin"`
   - `import Bee from "@mailupinc/bee-plugin"`
   - `import * as Bee from "@mailupinc/bee-plugin"`
   - `const Bee = require "@mailupinc/bee-plugin"`

None of them seem to work. Why? 
I always get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Bee is not defined`

For reference
application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "./bee";
```

webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack");

// Avoid using require and import and alias jquery
environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
  })
);

module.exports = environment
```

bee.js

```
import Bee from "@mailupinc/bee-plugin";

function initBee() {
  $.ajax({ url: "/editor/token", success: startBee });
}

function beeConfig() {
  return {...} // Config params
}

function startBee(auth) {
  const beeInstance = Bee.create(auth, beeConfig(), (instance) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: $("#bee-plugin-container").data("template"),
      success: (template) => instance.start(template),
    });

    return instance;
  });
}

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", initBee);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was nothing wrong with the import.

Turns out the library will asynchronously import an external script during the initialisation of an instance and that script was where the `create` method was defined ([source code here](https://github.com/BEE-Plugin/Bee-plugin-official/blob/master/src/bee.js#L11))

The file now looks like

```
import Bee from "@mailupinc/bee-plugin";

function initBee() {
  $.ajax({ url: "/editor/token", success: startBee });
}

function beeConfig() {
  return {...}
}

function startBee(auth) {
  $.ajax({
    url: $("#bee-plugin-container").data("template"),
    success: (template) => new Bee(auth).start(beeConfig(), template),
  });
}

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", initBee);
```